# What are the differences between 'fairseq' and 'fairseq2'?

Tags: deep-learning, frameworks, open-source, language-model, fairseq

What are the differences between [fairseq](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fairseq) and [fairseq2](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fairseq2)?

Quotes from the github pages are not very clear

> Fairseq(-py) is a sequence modeling toolkit that allows researchers
> and developers to train custom models for translation, summarization,
> language modeling and other text generation tasks.

and

> fairseq2 is a sequence modeling toolkit that allows researchers and
> developers to train custom models for translation, summarization,
> language modeling, and other content generation tasks. It is also the
> successor of fairseq.

So far I realized there're `API` changes (for example, model loading from checkpoint), and the addition of new multimodal such as `Seamless communication`,
but why abandon a well-established framework and start from scratch?